# NodeJS: forever.js throws binding error : EROFS read only file system

Tags: node.js, vps, centos6, forever

Okay, so I am using nodejitsu's forever(v0.11.1) module to keep my NodeJS(v0.10.28) + expressJS(3.5.1) server running on VPS(CentOS-6.4).  
 Everything was working smoothly untill recently when I started getting following error while running command: forever start server.js  
 As soon as I run this command I got the following error:  
[image: Image showing error while running forever]

I tried to see the file: ls - l /root/.forever/tVYM.log, No such file was found  
 
When I tried to start my node server using pm2, I got the following error:  
[image]  
I don't understand why is this happening even if I am root(su) user. Also, if I try to edit my server.js file, CentOS won't let me edit file and warns me about insufficient privilege.

But when I rebooted VPS and used forever, things were okay again but after some time, my server went down again and when I used forever to run my node app, forever threw the same error.  
I just can not see reason behind this.  
Thanks in advance

Comment: see [this](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line), explicitly put your logs in a directory you have access to (e.g. a users home folder).

Comment: Is your file system read only? Maybe it got corrupted and emergency switched to ro? Check with "mount" and "dmesg".